# Firefox Addon-SDK unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I tried to start with unit testing under Firefox Addon SDK 1.14 with Firefox 25.

Referring to https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/unit-testing.html I hoped that my test would print something to the console.

```
const {DateFormatter, NumberFormatter} = require("./formatter");

exports['test NumberFormatter'] = function (assert) {
    assert.pass('Unit test running!');
    assert.ok(NumberFormatter.format !== null, 'NumberFormatter available');
};

exports["test NumberFormatter async"] = function (assert, done) {
    assert.pass("async Unit test running!");
    done();
};

require("sdk/test").run(exports);
```

The result is:

```
(d:\Nabor\Entwicklung\2013\addon-sdk) d:\Nabor\Entwicklung\2013\skynet\packages\formatter>cfx test
Using binary at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'.
Using profile at 'c:\temp\nabor\tmptzmpba.mozrunner'.
Running tests on Firefox 25.0/Gecko 25.0 ({ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}) under winnt/x86-msvc.
...
3 of 3 tests passed.
Total time: 1.588000 seconds
Program terminated successfully.
```

I miss the informations from the example?

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing: missing --verbose flag

```
cfx --verbose test
```